# How do I convert an anonymous class to lambda expression and vice versa in vscode?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I see that vscode supports this type of source action for Java but do not see any documentation regarding specific commands to actually execute the operation.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Where did you see that? Just because you saw it on the internet, doesn't mean it's true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There was a hint on the official documentation https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/java/java-editing#_other-code-actions-supported : "Convert anonymous class to lambda expression".

First things first, you have to install the "Language Support for Java(TM) by Red Hat" Plugin: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.java
VS Code doesn't offer any advanced Java features out of the box.

And to convert an anonymous class to lambda, you just have click on the light bulb:

[image]

(in my case, IFoo is an @FunctionalInterface)

Comment: Thanks, I already had that extension installed but didn't notice those options previously.

Comment: Another option is: right click / Refactor...(`Ctrl+Shift+R`) / Convert to lambda expression